# Create a Google Earth Tour from a KML

Tags: google-earth, kml

I have a KML with a path. I would like to "fly" along that path with Google Earth. If I go to the *Play Tour* button below my places, it zooms out so I see the entire route, and then a litte play head runs for 15 seconds, but it does not go along the path.

How can I do this correctly?